# Find and replace text in Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this Javascript:

```
var = "<form action="/issues/[[issue_id]]/create-condition/" method="post" class="r_issueform" name="testform">"
```

And I have this HTML on the same page:

```
<input type="hidden" class="issue" name="issue_name" value="20"/>
```

Now with Javascript I want to replace the issue_id with value of hidden textbox.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: **#1:** Incorrect JavaScript. `var = "<form...`?

Comment: name of variable, quotes conflict :(

Comment: that was just example and typo. my main concern is how to replace the text in variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C37Jh/) jsFiddle example. Added the correct var declaration.

```
var form = '<form action="/issues/[[issue_id]]/create-condition/" method="post" class="r_issueform" name="testform">';

form  = form.replace('[[issue_id]]', $('input.issue').val());
```

Comment: thanks that was simple and worked